java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Please Call PESDK.init() in Application onCreate - How to Fix?
Stack trace I'm facing a crash in my Android app using the Video Editor SDK (VESDK). The error occurs when launching an activity that extends ImgLyActivity. Below is the stack trace:
    at ly.img.android.pesdk.ui.activity.ImgLyActivity.setTheme(ImgLyActivity.java:153)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4129)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4322)
    ...
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Please Call PESDK.init() in Application onCreate
    at ly.img.android.e.b(:9)
    at ly.img.android.PESDK.getAppContext()
    ...

The issue seems to be related to the PESDK.init() method not being called during app initialization. I have tried the following:
Adding PESDK.init(this) in the onCreate method of my Application class.
Ensuring the Application class is correctly declared in the AndroidManifest.xml.
However, the crash still occurs.
My Questions:
What is the correct way to initialize PESDK in the Application class?
Is there any specific configuration or dependency required to ensure PESDK.init() is properly set up?
Here’s my current implementation of the Application class:
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        PESDK.init(this);
    }
}

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Environment:
App Version: 1.2.4
VESDK Version: 3.2.0
Android Version: 14
Thanks in advance!
